# File in subpackage not taken into account

Tags: python, py2exe, distutils, setup.py

I am trying to create an .exe out of my project, but py2exe seem to fail since I added a lib subpackage in which I include external libraries.

Here is how my project is set up :

```
C:.
¦   LICENSE
¦   README.markdown
¦   requirements.txt
¦   run.sh
¦   setup.py
¦   TODO
¦
+---data
¦   +---input
¦   +---output
+---doc
¦
+---facemovie
¦   ¦   Eye.py
¦   ¦   Face.py
¦   ¦   Facemovie.py
¦   ¦   Facemoviefier.py
¦   ¦   FaceParams.py
¦   ¦   Guy.py
¦   ¦   training_types.py
¦   ¦   __init__.py
¦   ¦
¦   +---lib
¦           exif.py
¦           __init__.py
¦
+---test
        context.py
        exif_test.py
        face_script.py
        test_script.py
        __init__.py
```

I do not want to include the test package, neither the doc and data folder into my exe. The root for my executable should be the facemovie package.

I am trying to create the executable through my setup.py file, which is the following :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
import facemovie

sys.argv.append('py2exe')


setup(
    name = "Facemovie",
    url = "https://github.com/jlengrand/FaceMovie",
    packages=['facemovie', 'facemovie.lib'],
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'includes': ['numpy', 'facemovie.lib.exif'] } },
    console=['facemovie/Facemoviefier.py'],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

As you can see, the main entry file of my application is Facemovifier.py.
Everything was running fine until I add the lib subpackage.

When I run the py2exe command, here is part of the output :

```
running install
running build
running build_py
copying facemovie\Eye.py -> build\lib\facemovie
copying facemovie\Face.py -> build\lib\facemovie
copying facemovie\Facemovie.py -> build\lib\facemovie
copying facemovie\Facemoviefier.py -> build\lib\facemovie
copying facemovie\FaceParams.py -> build\lib\facemovie
copying facemovie\Guy.py -> build\lib\facemovie
copying facemovie\training_types.py -> build\lib\facemovie
copying facemovie\__init__.py -> build\lib\facemovie
copying facemovie\lib\exif.py -> build\lib\facemovie\lib
copying facemovie\lib\__init__.py -> build\lib\facemovie\lib
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Facemovie-0.4-py2.7.egg-info
Writing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Facemovie-0.4-py2.7.egg-info
running py2exe
.......
Adding python27.dll as resource to C:\Users\jll\perso\workspace\FaceMovie\dist\Facemoviefier.exe
The following modules appear to be missing
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'Numeric', 'Pyrex.Compiler.Main', '__svn_version__', '_curses', '_scproxy', 'configparser', ...,  'lib.exif']
```

As you can see, the lib/exif file is actually copied, but not found afterwards.

When I try to run the executable, here is the output :

```
C:\Users\jll\perso\workspace\FaceMovie\dist>Facemoviefier.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Facemoviefier.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "Facemovie.pyc", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lib.exif
```

And here is the line of Facemovie.py that causes the error :

```
import lib.exif as exif
```

I tried various things and read a lot of docs the last days, but was never able to understand what the problem come from. I have **init**.py files as required, and My Python code runs without any problem.

I would really appreciate any hint.

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

Finally solved the problem. 
@mata had the right solution (although I had tried these lines before posting here).

The actual problem was coming from the fact that py2exe starts by copying my py files in

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

and apparently use them to create the exe. 
During creation, they are compiled to .pyc.

Further creation of the executable was **skipping the compilation because the site-packages folder was already containing .pyc files**.

I found a temporary solution in removing those files using an ant target before building, but I wonder whether this is good pratice or not.

**Shouldn't py2exe avoid copying anything into the site-packages until I reached stable state ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
import lib.exif as exif
```

try:

```
import facemovie.lib.exif as exif
# or
from facemovie.lib import exif
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already tried both, without any change :s. What seem really weird for me is that the missing lib is always lib.exif, whatever import I do for this line